# React Navigation error: not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I realize why this occurring but am trying to figure out the best way to go about getting the required behavior:

Let's say I have a tab navigator and inside those tabs I have stack navigators.  When I first open the app I am in the Home tab.  Now let's say a push notification comes in and I handle that and say go to this screen in the profile stack navigator.  The screen is not usually the first screen in the navigator but because I have not navigated to the profile screen via the tab navigator the initial screen is not loaded so it's the first in the stack.  If I call `navigation.pop` it will not be handled by a navigator because their is no screen to go back to in the profile navigator.

I figured I could just call `navigation.navigate('Profile')` and it does navigate to that screen but it doesn't pop the initial screen so clicking the tab by default will now make the first screen the base screen until the app is restarted.

If I call `navigation.goBack()` I won't run into the above problem but I won't be able to always ensure that the 'Profile' screen is the place it goes back to.

Ideally I'd like some way to say push this screen into this stack and then push this screen.  So when pop is called it will always show that users profile screen.

** EDIT **

After looking through some docs I found that I can do the following:

```
    navData.dispatch(() => {
      navData.navigate('Home', {
        screen: 'ProfileScreen',
      });
      navData.navigate('Home', {
        screen: 'ProfileScreen',
        params: {
          screen: 'ViewPostScreen',
          params: { shouldPlay: true },
        },
      });
    });
```

Though I get the following warning: `Possible unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object 'action.target'`

I'm also using this logic in another location of my app with a different screen and works in development but not in production.  Looking for suggestions on to best handle the above situation.